# Are there benefits to placing ASP.Net code in a separate file?

Tags: asp.net

Are there benefits to placing ASP.Net code in a separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place your code in a separate file, many of your errors will be caught by the compiler BEFORE you actually run your site. It's always better to fix compile time errors, rather than run-time ones.

Answer (score 1):

it's useful to make  a [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and you really don't want a [tag soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup)